# Magento Multi site instance with 2 IP addresses

Tags: apache, dns, ssl-certificate, plesk

We're adding a second storefront to our existing Magento instance. The two store fronts will be accessed by different domain names and would have to have separate IP address to differentiate the payment charges on the customer's CC (so I am told by Authorize.net) and add SSL certificate to both.

My server support has no idea how to point a different domain name over to the magento instance since it's on a different IP address and the hosting company support team has said it can't be done. **I am being told to build a new Magento instance**, but I find that hard to believe. There must be other multisite instances on different IP addresses.

How do I set up multiple IP addresses on one server which share the same document root in PLESK?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I have refined the question to be programming specific with feedback from magento.stackexchange.com - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110625/multi-site-instance-with-2-ip-adddresses.

Comment: You should look at the [help/on-topic]. A programming question relates to how to program something with a programming language. You appear to be doing server config which isn't programming according to the help centre.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this approach which may be not compatible with Magento:

1. You have subscription example.tld with Magento on IP1.
2. Create new subscription on IP2 with name of your new front domain.
3. In subscription of new front place in `/httpdocs/index.html` content:

   `<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <TITLE>!!!! replace it with your page title!!!!</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <FRAMESET>
   <FRAME SRC="https://your-new-front.tld/" NORESIZE>
   <NOFRAMES>
   Your browser does not support frames.
   </NOFRAMES>
   </FRAMESET>
   </HTML>`

There is another approach to create custom virtual host for web server(nginx or apache) with new fron domain name and IP2 which web root points to old front but if you have separate SSL certificate for new front you need to maintain this certificates files manually, it will be quite hard. Plus extra maintenance of backup/restore of this configuration.

Third approach with customizing web server configs template from `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/` (as I understand there just need additional IP and server name in your current virtual server config). It's gives you no extra backup/restore.

P.S.
We have this pain just because current Plesk design doesn't allow 2 IPv4 address for single subscription.